# Не работают уведомления на Android 8 и выше

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Я пытаюсь вывести самое простое тестовое уведомление в своем андроид приложении, но сталкиваюсь с тем что уведомление просто не выводится.
Вот текст метода:

```
public void notification(View view) {
       Button button = findViewById(R.id.button6);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                       new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "IDK")
                               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_notifications_active_24)
                               .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                               .setContentText("Текст")
                               .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

               NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                       NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);
               notificationManager.notify(101, builder.build());
           }
       });
   }
```

разбираясь я увидел что в классе NotificationCompat(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat) присутствует объявление androidx.core.R (картинка 1) но такого класса там нет(зато есть в android.R). Из-за этого скорее всего и ошибка, но как это исправить?[image: картинка 1]

Comment: класс R генерируется при сборке. скомпилируйте - и появится

Comment: Это не ошибка, класс `androidx.core.R` не является частью публичного API, поэтому не виден в IDE. Проблема скорее всего в том, что вы передаёте билдеру имя канала `"IDK"`, но сам канал не создали: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Priority

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы уведомления заработали на API 26 (Android 8) и выше, необходимо зарегистрировать [канал уведомлений](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels).

Сначала придумайте какой-нибудь `id` и `name` для канала:

```java
String id = "DEFAULT"
String name = "Все уведомления"
```

Зарегистрируйте новый канал при запуске приложения:

```java
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

Теперь, чтобы показать пользователю уведомление, используйте `id` созданного канала:

```java
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
    // далее ваш код из вопроса
```

Каналы уведомлений нужны для того, чтобы пользователь вашего приложения мог гибко настраивать, какие уведомления он хочет видеть, а какие нет. Кроме этого, в зависимости от выставленного [приоритета](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance), система Android может по-разному обрабатывать разные каналы.