# Почему не работает notification в Android на Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, уведомления, android-notification

Приложение запускается без ошибок, но при нажатии на кнопку - уведомление не появляется.
В настройках телефона по умолчанию - показ уведомлений разрешен

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 101
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "channelID"
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            // Создаём уведомление
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                .setContentText("Текст уведомления")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())

           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так уведомления все-таки в телефоне или в Android Studio?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работают уведомления на Android 8 и выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437791/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android-8-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с API 26 (Android 8 и выше), чтобы работали уведомления, необходимо зарегистрировать [Notification Channel](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels). Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```kotlin
val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Comment: Всё заработало, благодарю!